# function to get percentage for progress bar with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this array:

```js
[{
    "id": "5b221edea8abbc4194a62b90",
    "name": "Job one",
    "tasks": [{
        "id": "5b221edea8abbc4194a62b91",
        "name": "Task 2",
        "status": "finished",
      },
      {
        "id": "5b221edea8abbc4194a62b91",
        "name": "Task 3",
        "status": "pending",
      },
      {
        "id": "5b221edea8abbc4194a62b91",
        "name": "Task 3",
        "status": "to_do",
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "5b221edea8abbc4194a62b91",
    "name": "Job two",
    "tasks": [{
        "id": "5b221edea8abbc4194a62b96",
        "name": "Task 5",
        "status": "finished",
      },
      {
        "id": "5b221edea8abbc4194a62b97",
        "name": "Task 8",
        "status": "accepted",
      },
    ]
  },
]
```

All tasks is the 100% of progress bar. There are 5 tasks in this case. 100% = 5 tasks.

I want to know what percentage the progress bar has, according to whether the task has status **"finished"** or not. In this case should be (100 x 2):5 = **40%** completed in progress bar.

Thank you!

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: It's `Array` of `Objects` - not a `JSON`

Comment: We don't just implement stuff for you. We provide guidance in case you are stuck. It doesn't seem like you are stuck - it just seems there was no attempt made in the direction you are looking for. Please read about [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you!

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal  There are 2 of 5 completed..

Comment: @Arkej  Appart from the extra commas at the end of some lines it's valid,.. I assume he's copy / pasted, and left out personal info, but left the comma's in by mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can flatten the array using `concat` and `map`. Use `reduce` to get the percetange.

```js
let arr = [{"id":"5b221edea8abbc4194a62b90","name":"Job one","tasks":[{"id":"5b221edea8abbc4194a62b91","name":"Task 2","status":"finished"},{"id":"5b221edea8abbc4194a62b91","name":"Task 3","status":"pending"},{"id":"5b221edea8abbc4194a62b91","name":"Task 3","status":"to_do"}]},{"id":"5b221edea8abbc4194a62b91","name":"Job two","tasks":[{"id":"5b221edea8abbc4194a62b96","name":"Task 5","status":"finished"},{"id":"5b221edea8abbc4194a62b97","name":"Task 8","status":"accepted"}]}]

let result = [].concat(...arr.map(o => o.tasks)).reduce((c, {status}) => {
  if (status === "finished") c.finished++;
  c.total++;
  c.percentage = (c.finished / c.total) * 100;
  return c;
}, {finished: 0,total: 0,percentage: 0})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: By providing the function written from scratch you're **(1)** encouraging questions with 0 effort; **(2)** not helping OP become a better programmer - because they didn't try to implement something. They will just copy paste this code without knowing what *magic* was used behind the scenes. **(3)** promoting a false idea that such questions are on-topic. So, even if the solution works (although is overly complicated), a hopefully significant -1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use nested  `forEach` for calculating the percentage.

Try the following:

```js
var arr =  [{"id":"5b221edea8abbc4194a62b90","name":"Job one","tasks":[{"id":"5b221edea8abbc4194a62b91","name":"Task 2","status":"finished"},{"id":"5b221edea8abbc4194a62b91","name":"Task 3","status":"pending"},{"id":"5b221edea8abbc4194a62b91","name":"Task 3","status":"to_do"}]},{"id":"5b221edea8abbc4194a62b91","name":"Job two","tasks":[{"id":"5b221edea8abbc4194a62b96","name":"Task 5","status":"finished"},{"id":"5b221edea8abbc4194a62b97","name":"Task 8","status":"accepted"}]}];

var completedCount = 0;
var total = 0;
arr.forEach((o)=>{
  o.tasks.forEach((task) => {
    if(task.status == "finished")
      completedCount++;
     total++;
  });
});
var percentage  = (completedCount/total)*100;
console.log(percentage+"%");
```

Comment: By providing the function written from scratch you're **(1)** encouraging questions with 0 effort; **(2)** not helping OP become a better programmer - because they didn't try to implement something. They will just copy paste this code without knowing what *magic* was used behind the scenes. **(3)** promoting a false idea that such questions are on-topic. So, even if the solution is indeed the right one, a hopefully significant -1 from me.